# What's a good Perl OO interface for creating and sending email?

Tags: perl, email, cpan

I'm looking for a simple (OO?) approach to email creation and sending.

Something like

```
$e = Email->new(to => "test <test@test.com>", from => "from <from@from.com>");
$e->plain_text($plain_version);
$e->html($html_version);
$e->attach_file($some_file_object);
```

I've found Email::MIME::CreateHTML, which looks great in almost every way, except that it does not seem to support file attachments.

Also, I'm considering writing these emails to a database and having a cronjob send them at a later date. This means that I would need a `$e->as_text()` sub to return the entire email, including attachments, as raw text which I could stuff into the db. And so I would then need a way of sending the raw emails - what would be a good way of achieving this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read the documentation more carefully, then two of your three questions would be moot.

From the synopsis of `Email::MIME::CreateHTML`:

```
my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
```

You obviously get an `Email::MIME` object. See methods [parts_set](http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME#parts_set) and [parts_set](http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME#parts_add) for so called attachments.

`Email::MIME` is a subclass of `Email::Simple`. See method [as_string](http://p3rl.org/Email::Simple#as_string) for serialising the object to text.

See [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email::Sender) for sending mail.

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [perl MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/).

You can get the message as a string to save into a database:

```
### Get entire message as a string:
$str = $msg->as_string;
```

Comment: I think that might actually be perfect! I knew there would be one somewhere! Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to introduce an altogether different MIME mail library.

Answer (score 1):

[Email::Stuff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Stuff) is a nice wrapper for Email::MIME. You don't need to care about the MIME structure of the mail, the module does it for you.

```
Email::Stuff->from     ('cpan@ali.as'                      )
            ->to       ('santa@northpole.org'              )
            ->bcc      ('bunbun@sluggy.com'                )
            ->text_body($body                              )
            ->attach   (io('dead_bunbun_faked.gif')->all,
                        filename => 'dead_bunbun_proof.gif')
            ->send;
```

It also has as_string.

Comment: Thanks for this. Email::Stuff looks ideal